# Helmet is displaying error when toast is displayed

Tags: node.js, express, toastr, helmet.js

Has anyone encountered this message while trying to display a toast while using Helmet?

The toast still displays but, I'm not sure why the error is.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser seems to be blocking this because `data:` images are not whitelisted in the content security policy. The `img-src` directive of your CSP looks like this:

```
img-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com
```

It should look something like this:

```
img-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com data:
```

You can use Helmet to set this policy like this:

```
app.use(helmet.csp({
  directives: {
    // ...
    imgSrc: ["'self'", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com", "data:"]
  }
}))
```